# How to show JSON parsed data in expandable listview?

Tags: android, json, listview, expandablelistview

I am using [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) method to display a custom expandable listview. It has a static data inserted. but in my app , i am receiving a json data and i am unable to parse it in a way to display it inside the expandable listview.

JSON data I recieve is

```
{
"success": 1,
"Message": "User exist",
"category": [{
    "major_item_id": "1",
    "Major_item_name": "Cement"
}, {
    "major_item_id": "15",
    "Major_item_name": "Wire"
}],
"subcategory": [{
    "major_item_id": "1",
    "name_item":"abc1"
}, {
    "major_item_id": "1",
    "name_item":"pqrs2"
}, {
    "major_item_id": "15",
    "name_item":"lmn"
}, {
    "major_item_id": "15",
    "name_item":"xyz"
}]}
```

What I want to is an expandable listview in format :

```
Cement //listHeader
-abc1  // child items
-pqrs2   // child items
Wire
-lmn
-xyz
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you have? You can't parse the JSON to the `List<String>` and `HashMap<String, List<String>>` that they are using in the link you've posted?

Answer (score 0):

An JSON file consist of many components. Here is the table defining the components of an JSON file and their description

```
Array([)
```

In a JSON file , square bracket ([) represents a JSON array

```
Objects({)
```

In a JSON file, curly bracket ({) represents a JSON object

```
Key
```

A JSON object contains a key that is just a string. Pairs of key/value make up a JSON object

```
Value
```

Each key has a value that could be string , integer or double e.t.c

Each implementations are different according to the json format that you have been used. You can easily find too many examples on internet.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: I know how to parse data , but i am unable to link Cement with abc1 , pqrs2 and how to show them in the method given by androidhive - link given above

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to convert the JSON to an object like this:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<YourObject>() {}.getType();
    YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(getCurrentChat(), listType);
```

Once you have the correct object you can use the corresponding values to update your ExpandableListView.